# PrimeFaces and org.tuckey urlrewrite filter

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting, primefaces

I have a problem using JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces and the tuckey.org UrlRewriteFilter.

The problem is, that if i add a PrimeFaces-component (e.g. ), the page (or wherever exactly the resources are coming from) doesn't load the core.js where the PrimeFaces-object is defined. Accordingly, the component doesn't load.

The core.js-file is located within the primefaces-2.2.RC1.jar (which is within the WEB-INF/lib of the webapp) within the folder META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js.

My urlrewrite-rules are the following:

```
<rule>
        <from>/</from>
<to>/faces/pages/public/welcome.xhtml</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/styles/**</from>
        <to>/styles/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/images/**</from>
        <to>/images/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/scripts/**</from>
        <to>/scripts/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/flash/**</from>
        <to>/flash/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/admin/*.xhtml</from>
        <to>/faces/pages/admin/$1.xhtml</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/*.xhtml</from>
        <to>/faces/pages/public/$1.xhtml</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/**</from>
        <to>/$1</to>
    </rule>
```

I guess it's a problem with my rewrite-rules, but i just can't figure out what exactly goes wrong. What i would need would be the URL that is used by PrimeFaces to load the core.js file, so i can analyze what the problems with my rules.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you all for your advices :)

Best regards,
Robert

Comment: Oops, sorry... i meant PrimeFaces-object :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i just found the answer. It was definitely no problem with the urlrewrite filter.
Instead, it was just a problem with my facelet-template.

the template used head and body tags instead of the JSF versions "h:head" and "h:body" and PrimeFaces requires the "h:head" tag to be present.